# how to put thread into ThreadPool in qt5

Tags: qt5

I create many threads that inherite from QObject. I want to put these threads into ThreadPool. How can I achieve it?

```
    class MyTask : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit MyTask(QObject *parent = 0);

    signals:
        void prepareFinish();
        void printFinish();

    public slots:
//thread invoke
        void prepareData();
        void printData();

    private:
        static int i;
        static QMutex *mutex;
        QWaitCondition bufferEmpty; 
        QWaitCondition bufferFull; 
        static bool flag;
    };

//MyTask is thread invoke task
```

Comment: what do you mean by `ThreadPool`? A `QThreadPool` class?

Comment: the thread that put into QThreadPool must be inherits QRunnable 
but MyTask inherits QObject
I don't known whether  exist other methods

Comment: There is no other way. Just inherit from `QRunnable`